# PIC16F1718 UART not working

Tags: pic, uart

I am currently trying to port the functionality of one of my projects from an Arduino to a PIC µC. To begin I wanted to establish a UART communication to my computer but I cannot get it to work. I tried with an TTL to USB converter and now with a logic analyzer to see if anything happens on the wire but there is nothing. I read in the datasheet the tx pin should be RC6 and I set all registers mentioned in the datasheet or in many tutorials and tried to understand them but I seem to forget something. Has anyone of you an idea?

**main.c**

```
#define _XTAL_FREQ 16000000
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <xc.h>

#include "uart.h"


int main(void)
{

    OSCCON = 0x7B;
    UART_Init(9600);

    while(1){              
        UART_Write('c');
        UART_Write('w');

    }
}
```

**uart.h**

```
char UART_Init(const long int baudrate)
{
  unsigned int x;
  x = _XTAL_FREQ/(64*baudrate)-1;               
  if(x>255){                                 
  x = _XTAL_FREQ/(16*baudrate)-1;               
  TX1STAbits.BRGH = 1;                          
  }
  if(x<256){                         
    TX1STAbits.TXEN = 1;                         
    TX1STAbits.SYNC = 0;                         
    RC1STAbits.SPEN = 1;                                                       
    SP1BRG = x;                               

    return 1;                             
  }
  return 0;                                     
}

void UART_Write(char data)
{
  while(!TX1STAbits.TRMT);
  TX1REG = data;
}
```

Comment: You might need pull-up or pull-down resistors on the UART line. Did you try analysing the ports with a scope?

Comment: I don't think that a standard UART connection needs any pull-up or pull-down resistors to operate. I observed the pin with my logic analyzer (like a cheap oscilloscope to keep track of the logic levels) and nothing happened.

Comment: Are you familiar with the configuration bits on PICs? If not, read about them (google "PIC configuration bits"). And find the configuration bits registers in the datasheet. Each PIC had it's own unique settings. In your case, it's most likely the watchdog timer is resetting the processor before it can send any data.

Comment: PICs do not need pull-up or down resistors on the UART lines.

Comment: I have heard of them but as I am a newbie I didn't come in touch with them till now. I will have a look but shouldn't things like this be mentioned in every datasheet section where they matter? Other people commenting simple UART problems don't seem to have similar problems.

Comment: The configuration bits transcend any one specific peripheral, so it would be tedious to describe how every individual configuration setting affects each peripheral in the datasheet. It's just part of the learning curve of using PICs. Every PIC uses them and you just get used to adding the code at the top of every new program. MPLAB provides an easy way to generate the necessary code.

Comment: Ok that sounds logical to me. I will dive into the matter in the next days. I hope it works afterwards. Thank you :)

Comment: "I read in the datasheet the tx pin should be RC6" - exactly where did you read that in the datasheet?

Comment: On page 5 in the datasheet. There was a table called "28-Pin Allocation Table" and in the "EUSART" column it says RC6 is the CK/TX pin.

Comment: also watch out that on some devices there are registers that assign certain IO pins to to device functions. Not sure if this is one of them but watch out for it. PIC config registers can have a few gotchas when you try to configure them by hand. You really have to read the data sheet carefully.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've missed some setup register(s). I don't see BAUD1CON initialization for example.

PIC datasheets are quite good in that they summarize all the bits that can affect each peripheral. You should check that you've set **each and every** (non-shaded) bit or byte or word below exactly the way you want.

[image]

There's another similar set for asynchronous reception.

---

That's the proper and thorough way to do it. You can also try using MCC (Microchip Code Configurator) plugin in MPLAB-X which allows you to pick options with check boxes and so on, and generates configuration code. You can redirect STDIO to the UART.

Take care with this, I've often run into subtle bugs in this sort of aid.

Comment: I read what the SCKP and BRG16 bits in the BAUD1CON register do. But I think they are fine when they are clear. SCKP is just for polarity and BRG16 affects the baud rate but when my SPBRG calculation is right I don't need it to be set, right? I guess it should normally work like I did and without MCC for beginning. MCC or config bits are never mentioned in all UART tutorials with PICs thats what I don't understand.